# Tag [maping] is a typo, which should be merged with [mapping]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

I believe the tag [maping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/maping) (currently 37 questions are tagged with it) is a typo and should be removed.

The existing questions should be re-tagged with [mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mapping).